# Resuable content list items in masterpage-SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint

If there is any way to use resuable contents from resuable content list being used in masterpage in SharePoint 2007?

Basically in the footer of the masterpage I want to create a link and the value of that I want to be editable per site collection. I read about resuable content list and I wonder if I can use it here, If not what other options I have?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest use a DVWP on master page that would solve your purpose as you can update the links in list and they would be updated in masterpage